# list of strings to a tuple of ints

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I'm new to python and am having trouble doing this conversion. How exactly do you convert a list of individual strings such as `['1','2']` and convert it to a tuple `(1,2)`. If it was simply a list it would be simple to just use `tuple(list_x)` but this seems more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tuple constructor to make a tuple from a list:

```
X = ['1', '2']
myTuple = tuple(X)
```

myTuple is now a tuple of strings: `('1', '2')`.

If you want to get a tuple of integers, you must first convert your list to a list of integers, and then use the tuple constructor.

The [int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function will convert a string to an `int`. We can use that plus a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) to get what you want:

```
tuple([int(s) for s in X])
```

Comment: remove the `[]`s to use a faster generator expression and avoid creating a temporary list: `tuple(int(s) for s in X)`

Answer (score 0):

List ['1', '2'] can be converted to tuple by line below:

```
l = ['1','2']
tuple_from_l = tuple(map(int,l))
print tuple_from_l
```

**Note:** Before converting to tuple i've passed list to [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert all item to **int** with [int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) method